# ECS service cannot pull from ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

ECS Fargate(ver 1.4.0) service creation is getting failed with below error

```
Resource initilization error unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ecr registry auth
Request error caused by post https://api.ecr.us-XX.amazon.aws.com timeout
```

Things i checked

1. ECS security group has all traffic allowed
2. VPC endpoint is created properly for ecr.api and ecr.dkr
3. ECS task execution role has permission to fetch image form ECR

Comment: Does your ecs service have internet access?

Comment: @Marcin no but we have created vpce endpoints

Comment: Probably they are incorrectly setup.

Comment: Timeouts indicate something blocking network traffic. I'd first check the security group that's attached to the endpoint, to verify that it allows access to the rest of the VPC. There's also the possibility of a network ACL that doesn't allow traffic. Or a bad routing rule for the subnet(s).

Comment: your ECS task nee dto have access to a IAM user, to do so you need to inject AWS_<creds> on load, before you may nee dto add AWS_<creds> into secrets-manager. then pull secrets directly from ECS task

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem! [This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/setting-up-aws-privatelink-for-amazon-ecs-and-amazon-ecr/) blog explains how to configure, and I forgot to configure another one thing: Private DNS. I had to enable it on ECR (DKR and API), and CloudWatch so it could reach put the service via FQDN.

Comment: What that article doesn't say is that PrivateLink comes at a cost (see [link](https://aws.amazon.com/it/privatelink/pricing/)), which it is not negligible especially if you have to create multiple VPC endpoints (S3, ECR, logs, etc.) and have multiple availability zones (i.e. subnets).

As an alternative, you have to enable Internet Gateway for your VPC, which is also a paid service.

It is totally insane one have to pay to pull container images from private ECR registry.

Comment: This solved it for me. Why is private DNS not enabled by default?

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same issue, (thought) I had the very same checks covered and this error was driving me crazy.

I actually solved it by realizing my security group for ECS tasks was limited to my VPC's CIDR block, even though the tasks will in a private subnet it needs full open egress and ingress access so it can access ECR, since it goes through the outworld internet.

So instead of something like:

```
ingress {
 protocol         = "tcp"
 from_port        = var.container_port
 to_port          = var.container_port
 cidr_blocks      = [var.vpc_cidr_block] #or cap later from ALB and ILB
}
```

You should have you SG for tasks opened like:

```
ingress {
  protocol         = "tcp"
  from_port        = var.container_port
  to_port          = var.container_port
  cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
}
```

And that's for both egress and ingress. Matter of fact after I added this I removed the VPC Endpoints and it still worked, they're not even needed. The role for grabing images is still necessary, though I just used AWS managed `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy`.

Comment: The ingress rule change is not necessary. With this ingress rule you allow the entire internet to access your containers. That is probably not what you want. Putting it in egress is enough, the firewall is stateful, meaning it will keep track of the outgoing connection and allow related incoming responses.

Answer (score 0):

While creating taskdefinition file with fargate compatability type. Enable AllowPublicIp to pull image from any registry(Public or Private).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).